# Passing constructor value to same implementation parameters according the context with autofac

Tags: autofac, named-parameters, constructor-injection

I have some mvc controllers must instanciate a single logger according the fully qualified controller name.

I try to explain with examples. I have this logger interface:

```
public interface Ilogger { ... }
```

and its implementation

```
public class MyLogger 
{ 
    public MyLogger(loggerName) 
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Well, I need now different loggers per controllers.

```
namespace Controllers
{
   public class MyFirstController
   {
       public MyFristController(Ilogger logger) { ... }

       ...
   }
}

namespace Controllers
{
   public class MySecondoController
   {
       public MySecondoController(Ilogger logger) { ... }

       ...
   }
}
```

I need two different singletons... One per controller, where the constructor parameter `loggerName` of `MyLoggerClass` must change according the controller. So, I need two instances:

```
new MyLogger("Controllers.MyFirstController")
```

and

```
new MyLogger("Controllers.MySecondoController")
```

I am trying something like this:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(assemblies)
    .PropertiesAutowired()
     .WithConstructorParameter(typeof(ILoggerProvider));
```

Where `WithConstructorParameter` is an extension method:

```
public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> WithConstructorParameter<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle>(this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> registration, Type targetType)
    where TReflectionActivatorData : ReflectionActivatorData
{
    return registration.WithParameter(
        (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == targetType,
        (pi, ctx) => ...)); // <-- I have been losing here....
}
```

Is it the correct approach? How can I solvemy problem?

Thank you

Comment: [Have you read the docs? There's a great example almost exactly this.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html)

Comment: Yes, I have seen that example... I have tryed to implement it but there was something I couldn't do... now I do not remember honestly because I have done different retries... I have solved with this line of code: `(pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed(pi.Member.DeclaringType.FullName, targetType)`

Comment: If you've solved it, you should post the answer to your own question so folks don't jump in here and continue trying to answer you. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the extension methos as following:

```
public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> WithNamedParameter<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle>(this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> registration, Type targetType)
    where TReflectionActivatorData : ReflectionActivatorData
{       
    return registration.WithParameter(
        (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == targetType,
        (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed(pi.Member.DeclaringType.FullName, targetType)
    );
}
```